# Use NSFontPanel to change foreground and background color of text in WebView

Tags: cocoa, webkit, nscolorpanel, nscolorwell

**The app:**

I have a Mac app in the Mac App Store with an embedded `WebView`. The WebView contains a `contenteditable` DIV acting as a rich text editor.

**Goal:**

I'd like to change the **foreground** and **background color** of the selected text inside the WebView via the `NSColorWell` → `NSColorPanel` mechanism.

**Problem:**

When I click on a color in the `NSColorPanel`, `NSColorPanel` automatically invokes `changeColor:` on the first responder.

The first responder happens to be a private WebKit class representing my contenteditable DIV: `WebHTMLView`.

The above mechanism ALWAYS changes the foreground color of the selected text. I need a way to decide if the foreground OR background color should be changed.

**Ideal solution:**

It would be great if `NSColorPanel` and `NSColorWell` could be configured to not automatically call `changeColor:` on the first responder and let my code handle the color change.

**Tried and failed:**

- Setting `usesFontPanel = false` is not an option, because it is a `WebView`, not a `NSTextView`
- Tried solutions suggested here: [NSButton subclass as colorwell & preventing NSColorPanel from touching the first responder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328386/nsbutton-subclass-as-colorwell-preventing-nscolorpanel-from-touching-the-first)

  - Subclassing WebView doesn't help, first responder is a private WebKit class
  - Temporarily switching first responder results in flickering (not acceptable)
  - App must be Mac App Store compatible

Comment: `NSFontPanel`, `NSColorPanel` or `NSColorPicker`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the action of NSColorWell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616181/how-to-change-the-action-of-nscolorwell)

Comment: @Willeke Not a duplicate, the solution in the question you referenced only works for NSTextView (usesFontPanel = false), I use a WebView. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

To intercept `changeColor:`, set `editingDelegate` of the web view and implement `WebEditingDelegate` method `webView:doCommandBySelector:`.

for example:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(WebView *)webView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)selector {
    if (selector == @selector(changeColor:)) {
        if (self.foregroundColorWell.active)
            return NO;
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This sounded promising, but doesn't work, I'm afraid. I can intercept and deny changeColor: , but the text color still changes. I suspect that the internal view that handles the contenteditable DIV still implements changeColor: and doesn't respect the editing delegate. I'm open for suggestions.